# Java Stream - Groupby based on child class and calculate sum from parent class

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Below are my entities:

Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product extends ReusableFields
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long productId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    String productName;
    String measurementUnit;
    //more fields and getters setters
}
```

Inward Outward List related to product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inward_outward_entries")
public class InwardOutwardList extends ReusableFields
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long entryid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(
    { "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    Product product;
    
    @JsonSerialize(using = DoubleTwoDigitDecimalSerializer.class)
    Double quantity;
    //more fields
}
```

Inward inventory having set of inward outward list:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inward_inventory")
public class InwardInventory extends ReusableFields implements Cloneable
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "inwardid")
    Long inwardid;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "inwardinventory_entry", joinColumns =
    { @JoinColumn(name = "inwardid", referencedColumnName = "inwardid") }, inverseJoinColumns =
    { @JoinColumn(name = "entryId", referencedColumnName = "entryId") })
    Set<InwardOutwardList> inwardOutwardList = new HashSet<>();

    //more fields

}
```

I have a list of inward inventories which I want to group by based on product. So, I want to do is

SUM(InwardInventory.InwardOutwardList.quantity) while grouping by based on InwardInventory.InwardOutwardList.Product.productName and InwardInventory.InwardOutwardList.Product.measurementUnit

I am new to streams, I know it can be done but not able to get exact solution. Can someone provide guidance or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a `Map` where the key is some representantion of a unique `productName` and `measurementUnit`, and the value is a Double.

First, you need to define the class that you'll use as the map's keys. The requirement for it is to implement **equals and hashCode** ONLY based on `productName` and `measurementUnit` fields. Else, you won't be able to properly aggregate the quantities into the map. If you follow [Vlad Mihalcea's advice](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) then you can't use the `Product` class as keys because it implements equals and hashCode based only on the `id` field. In the example below `Pair<L, R>` has properly implemented equals and hashCode based on the `L` and `R` fields.

```java
List<InwardInventory> inwardInventoryList = ...;

Map<Pair<String, String>, Double> map = inwardInventoryList.stream()
        .flatMap(i -> i.getInwardOutwardList().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> Pair.of(l.getProduct().getProductName(), l.getProduct().getMeasurementUnit()),
                InwardOutwardList::getQuantity,
                Double::sum));
```

The first operation is a `flatMap` because every `InwardInventory` has a `Set<InwardOutwardList>`, but we want a single stream of `InwardOutwardList` objects.

The second operation is the `Collectors.toMap` defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

Comment: Thanks @Dan. This worked. I tweaked it a little to convert into an object instead of map. But the logic worked.

Answer (score 0):

I created simple classes from your code since the annotations are not required.

Class `Product`

```java
public class Product {
    private Long  productId;
    private String  measurementUnit;
    private String  productName;

    public Product(Long productId, String measurementUnit, String productName) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.measurementUnit = measurementUnit;
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public Long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public String getMeasurementUnit() {
        return measurementUnit;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
}
```

Class `InwardOutwardList`

```java
public class InwardOutwardList {
    private Long  entryid;
    private Product  product;
    private Double quantity;

    public InwardOutwardList(Long entryid, Product product, Double quantity) {
        this.entryid = entryid;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Long getEntryid() {
        return entryid;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public Double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

Finally, class `InwardInventory` which contains method `main` that demonstrates how to use the stream API to achieve your desired result.
(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class InwardInventory {
    private Long  inwardid;
    private Set<InwardOutwardList>  inwardOutwardList = new HashSet<>();

    public InwardInventory(Long id) {
        inwardid = id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product p1 = new Product(1L, "unit", "Product_1");
        Product p2 = new Product(1L, "unit", "Product_1");
        InwardOutwardList ioLst = new InwardOutwardList(1L, p1, 1D);
        InwardOutwardList ioLst2 = new InwardOutwardList(2L, p2, 2D);
        InwardInventory ii = new InwardInventory(1L);
        ii.inwardOutwardList.add(ioLst);
        ii.inwardOutwardList.add(ioLst2);
        Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics> map = ii.inwardOutwardList.stream()
                                                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(iol -> iol.getProduct().getProductName(),
                                                                                    Collectors.summarizingDouble(InwardOutwardList::getQuantity)));
        map.forEach((p, s) -> System.out.println(p + " = " + s.getSum()));
    }
}
```

- `ii.inwardOutwardList.stream()` creates a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) where every element in that stream is an instance of `InwardOutwardList`.
- the [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) method has a single argument whose type is [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html).
- Class [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) is a utility class that contains methods that return special kinds of collectors.
- the `collect` method returns a `Map` where the map key is the product name – extracted from class `Product` and the map value is an instance of class `DoubleSummaryStatistics`.
- method `getSum`, in class `DoubleSummaryStatistics` returns, in this case, the sum of the quantities.

Running above code produces the following result:

```
Product_1 = 3.0
```